# Select all rows button in flexigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I'd like the auto-select all the rows of my flexigrid. I guess I should somehow use

```
.addClass('trSelected')
```

or something like that, but to what elements ?

To call the flexigrid, I use

```
var gridSelector = "#createBordereauFlexigrid";
var gridOptions = {
 url: '_v2_db2Request.php?req=READ-DEPOSIT-SLIP',
 dataType: 'json',
 colModel : [   
  {display: 'Id', name: 'registrationaccountid', width: 40, sortable: false, align: 'left'},
  {display: 'Date', name: 'paymentdate', width: 60, sortable: false, align: 'left'} ],
 buttons : [ {name: 'Tout sélectionner', onpress: selectAllFunction}} ],
 title: 'Sélection des paiements',
 rp: 1000,
 showTableToggleBtn: false,
 resizable: true,
 width: 700,
 height: 310,
 singleSelect: false,
 usepager: false,
 useRp: false
}

$(gridSelector).flexigrid(gridOptions);
```

And usually I would use something like this the get the selected rows and ids.

```
function sellectAllFunction(com, grid) {
 var ids = [];
 $('.trSelected',grid).each(function() {
  var pattId = /^row([0-9]+)$/;
  var match = pattId.exec($(this).attr('id'));

  ids.push(match[1]);
 });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a part of your HTML?

Comment: I edited my original post to include code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, I found my solution.

```
function selectAllFunction(com,grid) {
 $( "#createBordereauFlexigrid tr" ).addClass('trSelected');
}
```

Pretty easy and straight forward, too bad there are no decent Flexigrid Tutorial!